# Unable to set the value and submit using getElementsByName

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

What I am trying to accomplish is to populate the text box (name of "reason") with the word "TEST" using Tampermonkey.
(I'm very new to using Tampermonkey & Javascript so please be patient with me.)

I am having an issue where the text box isn't populating with the word "TEST" and isn't submitting automatically.

Would you be able to provide assistance?
Let me know if you need anything.

This is my Tampermonkey code:

```
function ClickURL() {
  var FillF = document.getElementsByName("reason");
  FillF[0].value = "TEST";
  FillF.submit();
}
```

This is the source of the webpage:

```
<div class="field-input">
<input class="" type="text" name="reason" required="required" title=""></div>
```

Edit: Removed unnecessary code

Comment: The `submit()` method only works on a `<form>`, not `<input>`

Comment: How should I modify my script so it works on <input> as well?

Comment: `FillF[0].form.submit()`

Comment: What does the second part of the code snippet have to do with this?

Comment: Removed the unnecessary code. Even after using FillF[0].form.submit(), it is still not submitting.

Comment: Can anyone provide a bit more info on how I can make my code work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to fill out the text field and submit automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59958600/unable-to-fill-out-the-text-field-and-submit-automatically)

Comment: Still not working. For some reason the value field is not being populated and it's just blank when checking properties.

Comment: `var TextField1 = document.getElementsByName("reason");
TextField1[0].setAttribute("value", "");
TextField1[0].value = "TEST";

var FormSub = document.getElementsByName("profileForm");
FormSub[0].submit();`
Anyone? @Barmar @wOxxOm @RASG

Comment: It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/qwhm1bzv/2/ I could see TEST flash briefly in the input field before the form submitted.